# REST API app - nested resources functions implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, taskmanager

I'm writing my first RESTful API app on ruby on rails as a part of a degree's course.
Final project is about to make a simple task manager with a base of users and an array of task for each one of them. I never worked with Ruby language before so tried to use some manuals over the internet. I succeed to implement people database, but I think I'd stuck with a part of a functions of tasks in Task controller, because it's nested resuorce-every user has own task list each task is unique for him.
I'm not really sure how to implement the next REST API commands:

**GET /people/{id}/tasks/** - Returns an array of tasks that the person with id id owns.

**POST /people/{id}/tasks/** - Adds the new task, as described by the request body, to the person whose id equals id. If the status field is not specified in the request body, the server will default to marking the newly created task as active.

I already defined the association between active records of person and tasks as has_many and belongs_to , just not sure how to implement that 2 commands,also i have to implement modify and delete, but first of all want to understand how to implement 2 commands mentioned above.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have 2 solutions, let's go through them together.

1st one, if you want implement it to follow this route `GET /people/{id}/tasks`

in your `people_controller.rb` you can do the following

```
before_action :find_user, only: %i[user_tasks]

def user_tasks
  tasks = @user.tasks
  render json: { tasks: tasks }, status: :ok 
end

private

def find_user
  @user = YourModelName.find_by(id: id)
  render json: { error: 'User not found' }, status: :not_found unless @user.present?
end
```

and I don’t recommend this way because it's not how we supposed to do it, you should do tasks crud in tasks controller

2ed way, in your `tasks_controller.rb` do the following

```
before_action :find_user, only: %i[create index]

def index
  tasks = @user.tasks
  render json: { tasks: tasks }, status: :ok
end

def create
  task = Task.new(task_params)
  task.user = @user
  if task.save
    render json: { message: 'task created successfully' }, status: :ok
  else
    rednder json: { message: task.errors.full_messages }, status: : unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def task_params
  # permit the task params here
end

def find_user
  @user = YourModelName.find_by(id: user_id)
  render json: { error: 'User not found' }, status: :not_found unless @user.present?
end
```

The route to create a task will be
`post '/people/tasks', to: 'your_controller_path#create'`
and the route to get the tasks for a specfic user
`get '/people/tasks', to: 'your_controller_path#show'` and don't forget to send the required params